# Makefile that prevents tex directory from being cluttered with build output

Tags: xetex, compiling, auxiliary-files, makefile

I am using `xelatex`, `biber` and `makeglossaries` to generate my bachelor thesis. All of them are creating a huge amount of temporary files that are cluttering, not only my root document directory, but the whole directory structure of my thesis. Previously I've made extensive use of `find` and `rm` in a `clean` target of my `Makefile` to get rid of all the crap.

Currently my idea was to to copy all the content that is needed to build the thesis in a `.build` subdirectory and `cd` into that directory inside the Makefile before beginning to compile. I tried to use `output-directory` switches of xelatex and biber (makeglossaries doesn't have one), but with no luck. That's why i want to generate the pdf inside a subdirectory, that i can safely remove with all the content, after the compilation and copying the created `pdfs`, using `rm -rf .build/*`.

Here is the Makefile (the interesting part in the `screen` or `print` target, as you will):

```
#
# Makefile for Bachelorthesis
#
# @ supresses command output
#
# conditionals are not allowed to have a starting tab, 
# otherwise they will be sent to the shell
#
DEBUG='true'
ROOT_DIR=$(shell pwd)
BUILD_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/.build
XELATEX_OPTS=-output-directory=$(BUILD_DIR)
BIBER_OPTS=--output_directory=$(BUILD_DIR)
.PHONY : clearscr clean screen print

all: copy_sources screen print copy_output

copy_sources:
    rsync --verbose --checksum --recursive --human-readable --progress --exclude=output --exclude=.git* $(ROOT_DIR)/ $(ROOT_DIR)/.build

copy_output:
    cp --update $(BUILD_DIR)/*.pdf $(ROOT_DIR)/output

screen:
    @echo "Building screen version ..."
    @cd $(BUILD_DIR)
ifeq ($(DEBUG) , 'true')
    @echo "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n"     
    xelatex thesis $(XELATEX_OPTS) | grep --ignore-case warning
    @echo "\n------------------- biber ---------------------\n" 
    biber thesis $(BIBER_OPTS)
    @echo "\n--------------- makeglossaries ----------------\n"         
    makeglossaries thesis
    @echo "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n" 
    xelatex thesis $(XELATEX_OPTS) | grep --ignore-case warning     
else
    xelatex thesis $(XELATEX_OPTS) > /dev/null  
    biber thesis $(BIBER_OPTS) > /dev/null          
    makeglossaries thesis > /dev/null   
    xelatex thesis $(XELATEX_OPTS) > /dev/null          
endif

print:
    @echo "Building print version ..."
    cd $(BUILD_DIR)
ifeq ($(DEBUG) , 'true')
    @echo "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n" 
    xelatex thesis_print $(XELATEX_OPTS) | grep --ignore-case warning
    @echo "\n------------------- biber ---------------------\n"     
    biber thesis_print $(BIBER_OPTS)        
    @echo "\n--------------- makeglossaries ----------------\n" 
    makeglossaries thesis_print
    @echo "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n"     
    xelatex thesis_print $(XELATEX_OPTS) | grep --ignore-case warning       
else
    xelatex thesis_print $(XELATEX_OPTS) > /dev/null            
    biber thesis_print $(BIBER_OPTS) > /dev/null            
    makeglossaries thesis_print > /dev/null 
    xelatex thesis_print $(XELATEX_OPTS) > /dev/null            
endif

clean:
    @echo "I will clean up this mess ..."
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
    # remove the following commands, if the build was started in the BUILD_DIR successfully
    @rm -f *.out *.nav *.snm *.toc *.log *.bcf *.bbl *.blg *.lof *.lol *.lot *.run.xml *.xdy *.glo *.glg *.gls *.idx *.ist *-blx.bib .*.bbl.swp *.mtc* *.maf
    @find . -name \*.aux  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.bbl  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.bak  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.blg  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.fls  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.fdb_latexmk  -type f -delete
    @find . -name \*.vsdx  -type f -delete
    @find $(ROOT_DIR) -name '*in Konflikt stehende*' -delete

clearscreen:
    clear
```

This is the root directory of the document after compiling, a horrible amount of temporary garbage:

```
    abstract.aux     _dump        synctooutput.sh   thesis.lol   thesis.mtc6       thesis_print.gls   thesis_print.mtc2  thesis_print.run.xml
abstract.tex     frontpage    synctooutput.sh~  thesis.lot   thesis.mtc7       thesis_print.ist   thesis_print.mtc3  thesis_print.tex
affidavit.aux    header       thesis.aux        thesis.maf   thesis.mtc8       thesis_print.lof   thesis_print.mtc4  thesis_print.toc
affidavit.tex    LICENSE      thesis.bcf        thesis.mtc   thesis.mtc9       thesis_print.log   thesis_print.mtc5  thesis.run.xml
appendix         license.aux  thesis.glg        thesis.mtc0  thesis.out        thesis_print.lol   thesis_print.mtc6  thesis.tex
attachments      license.tex  thesis.glo        thesis.mtc1  thesis.pdf        thesis_print.lot   thesis_print.mtc7  thesis.toc
bibliography     Makefile     thesis.gls        thesis.mtc2  thesis_print.aux  thesis_print.maf   thesis_print.mtc8  tikz_pgf
bibtexEntry.tex  output       thesis.ist        thesis.mtc3  thesis_print.bcf  thesis_print.mtc   thesis_print.mtc9  todos.sh
content          README       thesis.lof        thesis.mtc4  thesis_print.glg  thesis_print.mtc0  thesis_print.out   variables
document.tex     resources    thesis.log        thesis.mtc5  thesis_print.glo  thesis_print.mtc1  thesis_print.pdf
```

It seems that xelatex and co are not using the directory that was set by the *output-directory*-switch, instead they use the *working directory* of the Makefile. I've even tried it /wo the option only using the `cd` command before starting to compile, with the same result.

Please help me to get rid of all the temp files :)

Comment: I think i got the issue, i forgot that `make` calls for every new line in the `Makefile` a new shell, that means that my `cd` has no effect on the commmands that are run below. When I've solved the issue i will post the solution.

Comment: Every commands of a rule start a new shell, to execute some commands in another directory use `cd $(BUILD_DIR) ; other commands ; ... ;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, maybe this helps someone else or it serves as an inspiration for creating Makefiles. The problem was the `cd` command and how `make` executes commands, like i mentioned i a comment above.

**Makefile:**

```
#
# Makefile for Bachelorthesis
#
#   Andreas Linz -- 10INB-T
#   HTWK-Leipzig, Fakultaet IMN
#   klingt.net@googlemail.com
#
# @ supresses command output
#
# conditionals are not allowed to have a starting tab, 
# otherwise they will be sent to the shell
#
DEBUG='true'
ROOT_DIR=$(shell pwd)
BUILD_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/.build
OUTPUT_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/output
#.PHONY : clearscr clean screen print

all: copy_sources screen print copy_output

copy_sources:
    @echo "Copying sources to build folder: $(BUILD_DIR)"
    @rsync --verbose --checksum --recursive --human-readable --progress --exclude=.build --exclude=.build_scripts --exclude=output --exclude=.git --exclude=.gitignore $(ROOT_DIR)/ $(ROOT_DIR)/.build

copy_output:
    @echo "Copying generated PDFs to output folder: $(OUTPUT_DIR)"
    @cp -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*.pdf $(OUTPUT_DIR)

screen:
    @echo "Building screen version ..."
ifeq ($(DEBUG) , 'true')
    .build_scripts/screen.sh $(BUILD_DIR) $(DEBUG) 
else
    .build_scripts/screen.sh $(BUILD_DIR) $(DEBUG)
endif

print:
    @echo "Building print version ..."
ifeq ($(DEBUG) , 'true')
    .build_scripts/print.sh $(BUILD_DIR) $(DEBUG)       
else
    .build_scripts/print.sh $(BUILD_DIR) $(DEBUG)
endif

clean_conflicts:
    @find $(ROOT_DIR) -name '*in Konflikt stehende*' -delete
    @find $(ROOT_DIR) -name '*conflicted copy*' -delete

clean: clean_conflicts
    @echo "I will clean up this mess ..."
    @cd $(BUILD_DIR); rm -r *

clean_all: clean
    @rm $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*

clearscreen:
    clear

# remove the following commands, if the build was started in the BUILD_DIR successfully
#   @rm -f *.out *.nav *.snm *.toc *.log *.bcf *.bbl *.blg *.lof *.lol *.lot *.run.xml *.xdy *.glo *.glg *.gls *.idx *.ist *-blx.bib .*.bbl.swp *.mtc* *.maf
#   @find . -name \*.aux  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.bbl  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.bak  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.blg  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.fls  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.fdb_latexmk  -type f -delete
#   @find . -name \*.vsdx  -type f -delete
#   @find $(ROOT_DIR) -name '*in Konflikt stehende*' -delete
```

**Build-Scripts:**

*screen.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# script for generating the print pdfs
# this script should be called from the Makefile in the document root
#
# check number of arguments with `$# -eq 0`
#

if [ $# == 2 ]; then
    echo "Changing directory to: $1"
    cd $1
    if [ $2 = 'true' ]; then
        echo "12345: $XELATEX_OPTS"
        echo -e "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n"     
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis #|grep --ignore-case --extended-regex "info|warning|error|^\([A-Za-z0-9]*\)"
        echo -e "\n------------------- biber ---------------------\n" 
        biber $BIBER_OPTS thesis
        echo -e "\n--------------- makeglossaries ----------------\n"         
        makeglossaries thesis
        echo -e "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n" 
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis > /dev/null
    else
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis > /dev/null  
        biber $BIBER_OPTS thesis > /dev/null          
        makeglossaries thesis > /dev/null   
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis > /dev/null
    fi
else
    echo "Number of arguments given: $#"
    echo "Usage: ./screen.sh path_to_build_dir [true/false]"
fi
```

*print.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# script for generating the print pdfs
# this script should be called from the Makefile in the document root
#
# check number of arguments with `$# -eq 0`
#

XELATEX_OPTS=""
BIBER_OPTS=""

if [ $# == 2 ]; then
    echo "Changing directory to: $1"
    cd $1
    if [ $2 = 'true' ]; then
        echo -e "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n"     
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis_print > /dev/null
        echo -e "\n------------------- biber ---------------------\n" 
        biber $BIBER_OPTS thesis_print 
        echo -e "\n--------------- makeglossaries ----------------\n"         
        makeglossaries thesis_print
        echo -e "\n------------------ xelatex --------------------\n" 
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis_print | grep --ignore-case --extended-regex "info|warning|error|^\([A-Za-z0-9]*\)"
    else
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis_print > /dev/null  
        biber $BIBER_OPTS thesis_print > /dev/null          
        makeglossaries thesis_print > /dev/null   
        xelatex $XELATEX_OPTS thesis_print > /dev/null
    fi
else
    echo "Number of arguments given: $#"
    echo "Usage: ./screen.sh path_to_build_dir [true/false]"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pdflatex` I'm using the

```
-aux-directory=
```

option for temp files, looks like `xelatex` has the same option but not tested.

Comment: Only MiKTeX accessories have this command line switch...

Answer (score 0):

I really do not understand why the TeX community finds it so natural that all "inputed" files have to have an "almost full path" hard-coded inside each file. If there was some \inputrelativetome input command, like the

```
#include "local_file.h"
```

in C language, then it would be almost effortless to rename a subdirectory, for instance. I follow the mantra that things should be as local as possible.

I like to use a build/ directory. And I use a package called [answers](http://ctan.org/pkg/answers) to generate solutions to exercises to be put at the end of the book ([my book](http://topologia-geral.ourproject.org/)). I finally found a simple solution to the "build directory" problem. I just invoke:

```
TEXINPUTS=".:../build/:$TEXINPUTS" xelatex -output-directory=../build/ topologia_geral.tex
```

The order ".:../build/" or "../build/:." should not be an issue, unless you intend to generate files with names that conflict with those in your source directory. But that's a bad idea, anyway...